# Issue changing the color of a markers icon with CSS in leaflet

Tags: css, vuejs2, colors, leaflet, icons

I want to change the color of my leaflet markers icon by changing `fill` with CSS. I gave a `className` to my icon and tried to change `fill` by that `className`, but it does not work. I tried it with L.DivIcon and L.icon.
I use Vue.js in my code, the JavaScript code below is in `mounted`.
Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
var marker_box = L.marker([-5,-10], {
  icon: L.icon({
    className: 'my-box',
    iconUrl: require('/Users/.../src/assets/box.svg'),
    iconSize: [25, 25],
    iconAnchor: [15, 10]
  })
}).addTo(map);
```

CSS:

```
.my-box{
  fill: red;
}
```

And this is my svg Icon:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24">
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <rect width="8.672" height="11.274" x="7.988" y="6.398" ry="0" 
   fill="#59f" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000109" 
   stroke-width=".309" paint-order="fill markers stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I do not understand why you would need an svg icon for this. you could simply add an empty `div` and setting a `background-color:#4e2828` and `border: solid black 1px`, in which case it would be much easier to change the background color.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow community ;)
Now, specifics, that should work `.my-box path {fill: red; } `
If you want to change rect, you need to do this `.my-box rect {fill: red; } `
Only there may be a problem with `fill="none"` so at the end add !Important if it doesn't work.

Comment: @loicEzt yes, it could be an option, but I have other complicated Icons that I want to change the color of and where I cannot use this method. I just took a simple icon for this example.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Thanks! :) I tried '.my-box path {fill: red; }' and '.my-box rect {fill: red; }' but it didn't work either.. And I didn't understand, what do I have to do with ' fill="none" ' ?

Answer (score 0):

I converted the example to vue, I change the colors in css.

```js
var {
  LMap,
  LTileLayer,
  LMarker
} = Vue2Leaflet;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 13,
      center: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),
      url: 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      markers: [{
        location: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),
        circleColor: '#ecc9c9'
      }, {
        location: L.latLng(47.413210, -1.211160),
        circleColor: '#ecc9c9'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getIcon(item) {
      return L.divIcon({
        className: "my-custom-pin",
        html: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24">
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <rect width="8.672" height="11.274" x="7.988" y="6.398" ry="0" 
   fill="#59f" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000109" 
   stroke-width=".309" paint-order="fill markers stroke"/>
</svg>`
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#app {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.my-custom-pin {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.my-custom-pin path {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet@1.0.1/dist/vue2-leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
    <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
    <l-marker v-for="(item, index) in markers" :key="'marker-' + index" :lat-lng="item.location" :icon="getIcon(item)"></l-marker>
  </l-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution in my code but it is still not working. I use Vue.js I don't know if I have to pay attention to something else. I put the function `colorMarker()` in methods and the `L.marker` in mounted. 
The only way I found to change the color, is to replace the color of fill with a variable in the svg like this `fill="'+fillColor+'"` , and to change the color of fill by giving a new value to `fillColor`. But this is probably not the best way to solve this..

Comment: Do you think the information about vue was redundant?. Unfortunately, this is the case when not all data is provided. A lesson for the future :)

Comment: Yes sorry I thought it wasn't important. I will specify my question :)

Comment: I did an example of a leaflet map in vue.

Comment: I use Vue.js and Leaflet separately, I didn't know there is a Vue2-Leaflet combination. Do you think it is better to use the Vue2-Leaflet combination? Is there a lot to change in the code if I switch to Vue2-Leaflet ? 
Thanks